# lazard correspondece

Tags: gr.group-theory

can we use Lazard Correspondence for p-groups of maximal class and why?

Comment: You can use the Lazard correspondence on any $p$-group of class less than $p$. So, in particular, you can also use it on $p$-groups of maximal class, as long as $p$ is larger than the class. This is useful for "asymptotic" statements, but if you are interested in results for a fixed $p$, or for all $p$, then you will have to bound the order $p^n$ of your group quite severely.


Comment: Your question could be improved if you follow some of the advice on the "how to ask" page, linked at the top of this one.